# How to avoid portforwarding in network programming

Tags: python, networking, server, portforwarding

I've tried programming chat application (server, client) but I have problem with receiving packets on my server. Application is working correctly but only when I have opened port my router. **My question is: is there a way to avoid portforwarding on router?** It would be better if my application could just make rule in firewall or something like that. Also, app is written in python and I'm using TCP protocol for connecting. Thanks for answers

Comment: Its common to have an intermediate server visible on the internet where all chat parties connect. The behind-router and behind-firewall clients are doing outbound connections, so they work (assuming the port itself isn't blocked .... that's why everybody cheats and uses 80). The server can then do multiparty chats, record everything, sell it on the dark web and eventually get caught up in a privacy scandal.

Comment: Make a rule in the firewall to forward the port, or put the box in the DMZ (if you have a nice enough router).  You should not try to get around basic TCP networking.